# Oracle Goldengate Big Data dblogin fails without error message

Tags: oracle, oracle-golden-gate, bigdata

I install Oracle GoldenGate for Big Data 12.3.0.1.0 for linux. After unzip and run start the manager I tried

```
dblogin userid username, password mysecret
```

and I got ERROR: Invalid command

I tried with Oracle GoldeGate (no big data bundle) and it works.
I check the gsserror.log file and there is no any error message.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Best,
Ignacio

Answer (score 1):

I fix it. It was my problem,  I was execution dblogin in the goldengate big data distribtion, I should do it in the goldate gate distibution.

Thanks